# SAP cloud sdk for javascript multiple and filters are directly appended: leads to "Expression can not converted into ABAP select options" on backend

Tags: javascript, typescript, sap-cloud-sdk

I have a read request to a ByDesign system and create in the following way:

```
const readRequest = QueryResults.requestBuilder()
            .getAll()
            .select(
                QueryResults.COFFMAT,
                QueryResults.CMATERIAL
            )
            .filter(
                and(and(
                    QueryResults.PARA_FISCYEARPER.greaterOrEqual(new BigNumber('0010000')),
                    QueryResults.PARA_FISCYEARPER.lessOrEqual(new BigNumber('0129999'))),
                    and(
                        QueryResults.CACCPSTDAT.greaterOrEqual(moment(validFrom)),
                        QueryResults.CACCPSTDAT.lessOrEqual(moment(validTo)),
                        QueryResults.CPERMEST.equals(PermanentEstablishmentID),
                     QueryResults.CACCBTT.equals(Constants.code.IssueForProduction)
                    ))

            );
```

And the request is generated in following URL encoding:

```
\QueryResults?$format=json&$select=COFFMAT,CMATERIAL&$filter=(PARA_FISCYEARPER%20ge%2010000L%20and%20PARA_FISCYEARPER%20le%20129999L%20and%20CACCPSTDAT%20ge%20datetime%272017-12-31T23:00:00.000%27%20and%20CACCPSTDAT%20le%20datetime%272020-12-31T23:00:00.000%27%20and%20CPERMEST%20eq%20%27P1100%27%20and%20CACCBTT%20eq%20%27344%27)
```

And here all the and filters are appended after each other which leads to an error thrown from the backend

> Expression can not converted into ABAP select options

The working filter url and also what I would expect the generated URL encoding to be (notice the brackets)

```
\QueryResults?$format=json&$select=COFFMAT,CMATERIAL&$filter=((PARA_FISCYEARPER%20ge%2010000L%20and%20PARA_FISCYEARPER%20le%20129999L)%20and%20(CACCPSTDAT%20ge%20datetime%272017-12-31T23:00:00.000%27%20and%20CACCPSTDAT%20le%20datetime%272020-12-31T23:00:00.000%27%20and%20CPERMEST%20eq%20%27P1100%27%20and%20CACCBTT%20eq%20%27344%27))
```

Can the second case be achieved somehow because in case of or filters the brackets are being generated properly, only with and they don't work.

Comment: Hi @CuriousCase, currently the SDK generates the URL without all the brackets that you expected, because logically they are the same. Unfortunately, it might be the case that some services don't support 2+ `and` operator and you need more brackets for splitting them into smaller pieces. I created a ticket to improve the SDK so that you can decide the structure of your filter. I'll let you know when it's released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 1.28.1 has been released recently. It should generate the url with more brackets that you need. See release notes [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/releases).

Comment: Thank you @Junjie Tang , I will try it out and update.